# NodeSet as character

Tags: r

I want to get a NodeSet, with the `getNodeSet` function from the `XML` package, and write it as text in a file.

For example :

```
> getNodeSet(htmlParse("http://www.google.fr/"), "//div[@id='hplogo']")[[1]]
<div title="Google" align="left" id="hplogo" onload="window.lol&amp;&amp;lol()" style="height:110px;width:276px;background:url(/images/srpr/logo9w.png) no-repeat">
    <div nowrap="" style="color:#777;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;position:relative;top:70px;left:218px">France</div>
</div>
```

I want to save all this node unchanged in a file.

The problem is we can't write the object directly with :

```
write.lines(getNodeSet(...), file)
```

And `as.character(getNodeSet(...))` returns a C pointer.

How can I do this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be a better way, until then you can capture what the `print` method for a XMLNode  outputs:

```
nodes <- getNodeSet(...)
sapply(nodes, function(x)paste(capture.output(print(x)), collapse = ""))
```

Comment: instead, use `as(nodes, "character")` for a character vector; `strsplit(as(nodes, "character"), "\n")[[1]]` for separate lines

Answer (score 3):

To save  an XML object to a file, use `saveXML`, e.g.,

```
url = "http://www.google.fr/"
nodes = getNodeSet(htmlParse(url), "//div[@id='hplogo']")[[1]]
fl <- saveXML(nodes, tempfile())
readLines(fl)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be a bit outdated but i got into the same problem and wanted to leave it for future reference, after searching and struggling the answer is as simple as:

```
htmlnodes <- toString(nodes)
write.lines(htmlnodes, file)
```